# The use of de instead of un

Tags: grammaire

This is the ending of the sentence:

> *[...] mais qui cache peut-être de lourds secrets.*

Why in this sentence is "de" being used?

I further searched up "*mais qui cache de*" on [Reverso Context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/mais+qui+cache+de)  and it gave a couple of examples with it.

Comment: Isn't the sentence ending actually: *mais qui cache peut-être de lourd**s** secret**s*** ?

Comment: yes sorry that was a typing error

Comment: You should edit your question with the correct spelling and adjust it if you believe it is still valid. ***Un*** can't be used with a plural for a starter.

Comment: how is it plural

Comment: Please edit your post with the actual sentence before asking for an answer (just click on *Edit* below the question to do it). By the way, do the same with [that other question of yours](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53556/the-purpose-of-the-preposition-%c3%a0-in-the-following-sentence) or delete it.

Comment: @Mifaas — You confirmed that the end of the sentence should read *de lourds secrets*, where the final s-es indicate the plural. My suggestion would be to edit the question accordingly; that way, you are more likely to receive a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use *un* instead of *de* in this sentence, you have to move it from plural *secret**s*** to singular *secret*:

> mais qui cache peut-être **un** lourd secret: *but that hides a terrible secret*

If it is not clear how many secrets there are, you would say:

> mais qui cache peut-être **de** lourds secrets: *but that hides terrible secret**s***

where *de* has now a partitive function. Note that:

> mais qui cache peut-être **des** lourds secrets

feels at least clumsy. I wouldn't use it.